# how to plugin evosuite.jar in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, evosuite

On the *evosuite* documentation website, they have a unhelpful video.

The video shows that when you right click the text editor in eclipse, there is an evosuite icon after "replace with", but I haven't figured out how I can do that after I tried different answers on website.

I put `evosuite.jar` in the **folder of eclipse plugins** and then use plug-in from Existing JAR Archives functions of eclipse to import it.

Am I anywhere close?

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the update site is here: http://www.evosuite.org/update/

Paste this URL into your Eclipse Install manager's work with text box (Help -> Install new software...), select evosuite and next. Follow the instructions to install.

Comment: it looks like the update site is down, is there any backup site?

Comment: How do you know it's down?  Did you navigate to the url in a browser? That would correctly give you a 403 error since the server does not allow directory listing in a browser.  You must add the url to your Eclipse update manager.  If that doesn't work, then you should contact the maintainers of the plugin to tell them this.

Comment: I assumed it is down because it don't work it eclipse, anyway I will contact the maintainers, thanks.

Comment: Have you any repsonse ? I have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to de-select the option “Group items by category” to see EvoSuite listed if you harness the power of Andrew Eisenberg's answer